# How to set arbitrary TreeViewTable expander column in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have TreeViewTable like image below:

**TreeViewTable**

[image]

I want to set the second column to be hierarchical (with expander as well) instead of the first column. The first column is vertically aligned and the second column is tree-like displayed.
I have tried for hours but couldn't figure out how. What should be the best approach achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy in javafx. You just need to call method `treeColumn(col)` of TreeTableView